# Symfony2 hook after template render

Tags: symfony

I've got a small question here: is there a way to do some actions after a template has been rendered ? A sort of Listener or hook which is called after a specific template has been rendered ?

In my case I want to know the last datetime the user visited the homepage. If I persist this value in the Controller, so before the rendering of the corresponding template, I won't be able to use my app.user.getLastHomepageVisit datetime variable in the twig template, as the value of the latter variable would be 'now' which is not what I want. I want to update and persist this value to 'now' *after* the page has been rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a hook on kernel.response:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html